# Linkedin Share API not returning all the fields

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am using linkedin share api for user login in my website. While login I fetch some information of the users from there linkedin profile. And linkeding in not returning the values of some fields even when user have updated my profile with those fields.

I am setting the scope as **'r_basicprofile r_emailaddress rw_nus'**

My linkeding fetching parameters code is as below

```
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,headline,picture-url,email-address,skills,public-profile-url,industry,positions:(title,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,size)),languages:(id,language,proficiency),num-recommenders,volunteer,educations,certifications:(id,name),publications:(id,title))');
```

I am able to get almost all the fields values, but not able to get values for fields like languages, publications.

Is there any thing wrong in my script, or I have to use some special method for that, as I have searched on google, I have found the same solution as I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For languages and publications you need `r_fullprofile` scope.

See https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#fullprofile for a list of fields that require the full profile.